# How to generalize this script for multiple popups on mouseover

Tags: javascript, popup, dom-events

I have a script that works to switch between two popups that are triggered by an `onmouseover` event. One feature of this is that the popup persists until the next `onmouseover` event. I want to have many of these and so the popup to be hidden can not be 'hard coded' as in my script. Is there a way to store in a variable the id of the popup that needs to be undisplayed the next time the popup function is called?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup(show,hide){
    show.style.display="block"
    hide.style.display="none"
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.pop {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table><tr>
<td onmouseover="popup(pop1,pop2)">Show popup 1</td>
<td onmouseover="popup(pop2,pop1)">Show popup 2</td>
</tr></table>

<div class="pop" id="pop1">This is popup 1</div>
<div class="pop" id="pop2">Popup 2 is here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

or go to http://www.salemharvest.org/Utilities/TestingPHP/testingpopupdivs5.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to generalize it is to use element index to show the associated popup. This will require that the popup elements (`pop` class elements) is contained by an element, in order to make both the *popper* and the popup element indexes mapped equally like two arrays of same length.

When showing a popup, the popup element is saved in a variable which will be used later when the mouse is on a different *popper* element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lastPopup = null;
  function showit(ev) {
    var popups = document.getElementById("popups").children;
    eleToShow = popups[ev.target.cellIndex];
    if (lastPopup && (lastPopup !== eleToShow)) lastPopup.style.display = "none";
    eleToShow.style.display = "block";
    lastPopup = eleToShow;
  }
  var poppers = document.getElementById("poppers").cells, i;
  for (i = 0; i < poppers.length; i++) {
    poppers[i].addEventListener("mouseover", showit, false);
  }
}, false);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.pop {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table><tr id="poppers">
<td>Show popup 1</td>
<td>Show popup 2</td>
</tr></table>

<div id="popups">
<div class="pop">This is popup 1</div>
<div class="pop">Popup 2 is here</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DickYates: See the updated code. The popup will be kept visible until the mouse is on different popper. Note that, your other code is responsible for closing the popup. Just make sure that code has access to the `lastPopup` variable or move the `var lastPopup = null;` line to the line before the `addEventListener...` line if you're unsure.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot follow the script you wrote (I will study it - I am a php guy trying to begin to wrap his brain around javascript and struggling), but I do follow your explanation in general. Matching the popper and popup ids will be easy as these will be genrated with a php loop. If I understand your method it is that the popup is hidden only when it, itself, has a onmouseout event. I think I can do that already. I want to be able to move from one popper to another and have the popup switch, AND to be able to move from a popper to its popup to, e.g. click links, copy text, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your update which does just what I wanted. Thanks! Now I have to figure out what it does and why it works. Also, what is wrong with my wishful attempt in my own followup 'answer'?

Answer (score 0):

I probably should have started with this, but my poppers will actually be rows, not cells. I tried what seemed like simple modifications of Jay's code to do it with rows. I changed it to index rows and then used rowIndex to find the popups, but I am missing something.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// function by Jay at stackoverflow
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lastPopup = null;
  function showit(ev) {
    var popups = document.getElementById("popups").children;
    eleToShow = popups[ev.target.rowIndex];
    if (lastPopup && (lastPopup !== eleToShow)) lastPopup.style.display = "none";
    eleToShow.style.display = "block";
    lastPopup = eleToShow;
  }
  var poppers = document.getElementById("poppers").rows, i;
  for (i = 0; i < poppers.length; i++) {
    poppers[i].addEventListener("mouseover", showit, false);
  }
}, false);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.pop {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 100px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="poppers">
<tr><td>Show popup 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Show popup 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Show popup 3</td></tr>
</table>

<div id="popups">
<div class="pop">This is popup 1</div>
<div class="pop">Popup 2 is here</div>
<div class="pop">And then popup 3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```